# Changing the look of <PreferenceScreen /> items

Tags: android, xml, preferencescreen

***The question:***

How do you change the text size used for the android:title attribute when the Preference items are listed in the settings menu?

***The details:***

The Settings screen in my app looks good on a Nexus 7 (Jelly Bean) tablet, but is almost unusable on a Motorola Defy (Gingerbread) phone. I am using the standard PreferenceActivity approach as detailed in the Android Dev guides.

I have been searching the web for several days, but have not found a solution that makes things look any different.

On the Android-Gingerbread phone;

1) the `<EditTextPreference android:title .../>` text is way too big, and doesn't word-wrap.

2) the standard "down arrow" icons next to each preference item look weird and misaligned.
([misaligned icon image](http://i.imgur.com/Dikme5A))

3) the theme is Holo, but a large blank region below the last preference item is an ugly light grey for some reason.

I've tried defining style.xml resources and putting style="@style/StyleName" in the preferences.xml to change the android:textSize attribute, but it didn't do anything.

Below is the XML for my preference screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/SettingsMenu" >

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:key="pref_key_mixProportions" 
        android:title="@string/pref_title_mixProportions"
        style="@style/SettingsMenu"
        >
        <EditTextPreference 
            android:key="pref_key_binderPortion"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_binderPortion"
            android:dialogTitle="Binder Portion"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:persistent="true" />

        <EditTextPreference 
            android:key="pref_key_premixPortion"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_premixPortion"
            android:dialogTitle="Premix Portion"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:defaultValue="5"
            android:persistent="true"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:key="pref_key_binderProperties" 
        android:title="@string/pref_title_binderProperties">
        <EditTextPreference 
            android:key="pref_key_binderDensity"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_binderDensity"
            android:dialogTitle="Density of Binder powder (kg/m^3)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:defaultValue="2850"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_binderDensity"/>
        <EditTextPreference 
            android:key="pref_key_binderBagWeight"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_binderBagWeight"
            android:dialogTitle="Weight of Binder per bag (kg)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:defaultValue="20"
            android:persistent="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:key="pref_key_premixProperties" 
        android:title="@string/pref_title_premixProperties">
        <EditTextPreference 
            android:key="pref_key_premixDensity"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_premixDensity"
            android:dialogTitle="Density of Sand and Aggregate Mix (kg/m^3)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:defaultValue="1850"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_premixDensity"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

My styles.xml contains:

```
<style name="SettingsMenu">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

But the text looks the same regardless of what value I give for the size.

I've seen that some people suggest using `<PreferenceScreen android:layout=".... />` but I've found no clear explanation of how this is done.

Can anyone help?

Comment: edit your post with the image link in it and Ill inline it or just post url here.  If you need to upload somewhere first, upload to imgur

Comment: "the theme is Holo dark" -- there is no `Theme.Holo` or `Theme.Holo.Dark` on Android 2.3.

Comment: Try using the ActionBarSherlock. That emulates the styles from newer Android versions.

Comment: HoloEverywhere is what you want if you're trying to replicate the Holo style on all platforms.

Comment: I've uploaded the image to imgur and edited the post.

Comment: I've re-written the app to use ActionBarSherlock. This has fixed the icon display problem. Thank you rekire. From my reading, I think HoloEverywhere would have also worked, as suggested by hwrdprkns.

Unfortunately this has not solved my Preference heading font size problem, so I'm going to try making a custom preference screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style file to the manifest declaration next to the prefernces activity - 
something like

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.PrefsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/PreferencesStyle" >
</activity>
```

that will do the trick